# Will manned aircraft have to defend ground targets against unmanned aircraft in the future?

Tags: military, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Given that current [Unmanned Combat Aerial Vehicle (UCAV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_combat_aerial_vehicle) development is mainly directed towards the strike role, is it most probable that a future manned vs unmanned combat aircraft scenario will involve manned aircraft attempting to defend ground targets against attack by UCAVs?

Comment: Too bad this was put on hold, there was a 2008 incident between Georgia and Russia where this thing happened: a Russian jet took out a UAV.  But given that this is speculation about the future, I understand why it was closed as opinion based.

Comment: My understanding is that the UAV in question was unarmed.

Comment: It was, but had it been armed it would not have mattered for that engagement.

Comment: If the UAV had been armed, it might have destroyed the fighter. An unarmed UAV or UCAV could also destroy a manned fighter with a mid air collision.                                                                                                
In such a deliberate mid air collision, the manned fighter's nose radome and cockpit canopy would be the prime targets. Either would be destroyed by the impact of a small UCAV since they are only designed to cope with bird strikes.

Comment: *If the UAV had been armed, it might have destroyed the fighter*  Fighter has speed, altitude, and visual advantage.  per von Richtofen "whomever sees the other first will most often win the fight."  Air to air engagements are a little more complicated than you are giving them credit for.  An actual UCAV with the AI and algorithms that can address the complexity and decision cycle of an actual dog fight is another matter entirely ... that particular drone in 2008 was nowhere near that advanced. A UCAV or other drone needs a speed advantage to ram a fighter.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to generalise too much about air to air combat. There's a big difference between a low speed, low level scenario and a medium altitude scenario.

Comment: If we consider a low level air to air scenario of the kind that might arise during a strike mission by UCAVs against ground targets, the UCAVs could detect the fighter using sensors in the visual and infrared wavebands and then manoeuver to ram or to engage with  guns or missiles, depending on how they were armed. The UCAVs would probably have equality in speed and an advantage in terms of high g manouvering capability, at low altitude. My guess is that the UCAVs would detect the fighter first, because they would have a smaller signature individually.

Comment: Assuming a one on one engagement would be a big mistake, when the probability is that it would be more like 20 to 1 in favour of the UCAVs.

Comment: A UCAV does not need a speed advantage to destroy a manned fighter with a head on collision. During the Second World War, Japanese fighters sometimes used this tactic against the B29 Superfortress bomber.

Comment: A collision course interception actually requires very little in the way of processing capacity. The USAF were doing computer controlled interceptions using the SAGE system in the 1950s. This was before computers became small enough to fit inside fighter aircraft.

Comment: Anyone who has played Microsoft Combat Flight Simulator knows that a laptop is actually a very tough opponent in a dogfight.

Comment: Fundamentally, computers and robotic systems have it all over human beings when it comes to tasks requiring rapid decision making, fast reaction times, and high levels of coordination. This is the reality that air forces around the world are working hard to deny.

Answer (score 2):

Some advantages of UCAVs over manned aircraft in the strike role:

1. The enemy doesn't gain hostages when they get shot down over enemy territory
2. The numbers that can be deployed are limited by the rate at which they can be turned out on automated production lines, not by the time it takes to train a combat fast jet pilot to a high standard (about 5 years minimum)
3. The UCAV can potentially be much smaller than a manned aircraft, if a reduction in range is acceptable, reducing the radar signature and vulnerability to air defence systems
4. As a result of 3, the UCAV can potentially be based nearer the area of operations and launched by catapult or using a rocket booster, leading to a shorter reaction time

In a scenerio where manned aircraft are intercepting UCAVs it is probably reasonable to assume that the UCAVs will have an advantage in numbers. UCAVs engaged in tactical missions will probably operate at low level and rely on superior manouverability and short range missiles to defend against attacks by manned fighters.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this was put on hold. The fact that that a UCAV doesn't need a pilot is just that, it's not a statement of opinion. All I've  really done is to draw a few logical inferences from that fact.

Comment: Basically, all arguments in favor of combat UAVs face the same problem - if it isn't fully autonomous, it can be incapacitated by disruption of control channel, and then it cannot use its advantage in speed/manouverability/numbers at all. If it is autonomous - we got ourselves a killer robot, what could possibly go wrong? /s And we cannot measure up these negatives against the positives at this moment due to us having no hard facts, only estimations of *possible* characteristics of UCAV. So the answer to your question is up to personal opinion, not to facts - thus it is closed.

Comment: Anyone who has any knowledge of military history knows that in war there are always a lot of things that can potentially go wrong, with or without robotic weapon systems.